# How to write unit test of a static void method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, httpclient, junit5

I am facing a problem, I don't know how to write unit test of static void method.

I have a HttpHelper class that using Apache HttpClient right now. Code like below.

```
public class HttpHelper {
    private static CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    public static void init() {
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(getDummySSL()).build();
    }

    public static void closeHttpClient() throws IOException {
        httpClient.close();
    }

    private static SSLContext getDummySSL() {
        ...omit
    }

    private static void send() {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://someUrl.com");

        try(CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
            if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                // do something
            } else {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So in my main I will call `HttpHelper.init()` to initialize the httpClient. Everytime I wanna send a request, i will call `HttpHelper.send()`. Because I don't want to create a new httpClient everytime. At the end, I will call `HttpHelper.close()` to close the httpClient.

I am wondering how to test those void methods. My concept is to create one `CloseableHttpClient` in my test, then call `HttpHelper.init()` to create the actual one. then compare my expected one and actual one is same. Am I right?

Due to the variable and methods are declare as static. It is a bit difficult to write unit tests. There are many posts said making methods static is a bad practice. However in my example, I don't know how to avoid declaring them as static and keep a single `CloseableHttpClient` instance.

Thank you!

Comment: Unit testing pain usually indicates a code smell.  Perhaps pass `httpClient` to `send()` (so `httpClient` can be easily mocked), or change to non-static, and inject `httpClient` (so `httpClient` can be easily mocked).

Comment: Hello, thanks for you reply. But if I doing so. maybe `httpClient` can't keep single instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a class so static is bad, because it's very hard to test this. I understand why you would want this, but you could have all the same benefits like that:

```
public class HttpHelper {

    private static HttpHelper DEFAULT_INSTANCE = null;

    private CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    public HttpHelper(CloseableHttpClient httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public static void getDeafultInstance() { // this should probably be synchronised for thread safety
        if (DEFAULT_INSTANCE == null) {
            DEFAULT_INSTANCE = httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(getDummySSL()).build();
        }
        return DEAFULT_INSTANCE;
    }

    private static SSLContext getDummySSL() {
        ...omit
    }

    public void closeHttpClient() throws IOException {
        httpClient.close();
    }

    private void send() {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://someUrl.com");

        try(CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
            if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                // do something
            } else {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could unit test it like that:

```
public class HttpHelperTest {

    @Test
    public testSendsRequestToSomeUrl() {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClientMock = mock();
        when(httpClient.execute(any())).thenReturn(..http_response_where_stauts_code_is_ok..)
        HttpHelper httpHelper = new HttpHelper(httpClientMock)
        httpHelper.send()
        verify(httpClient).execute(new HttpGet("https://someUrl.com"))
    }

}
```

and use it in actual code like that:

```
HttpHelper.getDeafultInstance().send()
```

P.S.

If you have some kind of dependency injection framework available, then you could get rid of the static methods at all.

Answer (score 1):

Single instance guarantee is mostly solved with the Singleton pattern. A common trick for unit testing is to make a constructor with protected visbility where you can put the arguments for testing. The class could finally look like this.

```
public class HttpHelper {
    private static HttpHelper INSTANCE = new HttpHelper();

    public static HttpHelper getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }


    private CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    private HttpHelper() {
        SSLContext sslContext = getDummySSL();
        this(HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build(), sslContext);
    }

    protected HttpHelper(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, SSLContext sslContext) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public void closeHttpClient() throws IOException {
        httpClient.close();
    }

    private static SSLContext getDummySSL() {
        ...
    }

    private void send() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would also rename the `getDummySSL` to `createDummySSL` but this is detail.